# MySQL Query issue with select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have two tables "client" and "proposal" in database,

**db.client = > id,name

db.proposal => clientID,proposalID**

`select * from proposal` will select all the clientID and proposalID
I want query, so that it print all proposal.proposalID with client.name instead of clientID

Comment: Start reading about SQL Joins

Comment: its confusing to me, i was considering that it will use inner join but confusing, i think inner join will not solve my problem. other solution i have to make a loop in php to get name against each id which is obviously the worst idea

Comment: @user794624 as Mark suggested you'd be best to read (more) about joins. Whilst I'd not use an `INNER` join here, there is one I would use.

Comment: thanks guys, however i am surly deserve for negative marking for such a stupid question, here its 4:15 AM night time, might be acceptable reason for this question,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach to "join" two tables:

```
SELECT proposal.proposalID, client.name
FROM client, proposal
WHERE proposal.clientID = client.id;
```

Warning: I didn't test this.

In order to understand what's going on, I suggest you learn more about SQL Joins.
Some links to get you started:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+join

Comment: Avoid using this old style syntax. It is ok for very simple queries like this but becomes messy with more complex queries. Using `JOIN... ON` keeps the join criteria next to the relevant tables and leaves the `WHERE` clause to only contain filtering criteria.

Comment: I just noticed this answer has been accepted. I wrote this to show another approach (besides using the `JOIN` keyword) but, as nnichols also pointed out, I suggest avoiding using this syntax, especially for complex statements.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29):

```
SELECT client.name, proposal.proposalID
  FROM client
  JOIN proposal
    ON proposal.clientID = client.id
;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. use [**join**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) of both tables.

```
SELECT c.name, p.proposalID
FROM client as c LEFT JOIN proposal as p
ON c.id=p.clientID
```

You should go through link specified to decide types of join. You can use  LEFt,RIGHT,INNER depends on exactly what you want.

Comment: Why a left join? It seems clear to me that the OP is asking for an inner join. (Or actually, for a right join, but I'm assuming that an inner join will give the same result as a right join for this data-set.)